# Geonetwork error: ERROR [geonetwork.wro4j] and ERROR [ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter]

Tags: geonetwork

Installation description:
OPENJDK 8,
TOMCAT 9,
POSTGRES/POSTGIS,
GEONETWORK (v3.10.1),
We use default data directory.

When we access the geonetwork web page we get the following errors in the log files:

```
ERROR [geonetwork.wro4j] - Error occurred during a wro4j request handling
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Cannot build valid CacheKey from request: /geonetwork/static/none
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.ResourceBundleProcessor.getSafeCacheKey(ResourceBundleProcessor.java:111)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.ResourceBundleProcessor.serveProcessedBundle(ResourceBundleProcessor.java:61)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.process(WroManager.java:159)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.processRequest(WroFilter.java:340)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.doFilter(WroFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.fao.geonet.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


ERROR [ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter] - Exception occured
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Cannot build valid CacheKey from request: /geonetwork/static/none
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.ResourceBundleProcessor.getSafeCacheKey(ResourceBundleProcessor.java:111)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.ResourceBundleProcessor.serveProcessedBundle(ResourceBundleProcessor.java:61)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.process(WroManager.java:159)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.processRequest(WroFilter.java:340)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.doFilter(WroFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.fao.geonet.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When we try to download a record as an XML or PDF file, only the browser page opens which displays the respective files, but no files are automatically downloaded. So we get the following errors:

```
ERROR [geonetwork] - URL -> http://nameServer:8080/geonetwork/srv/ita/../../images/logos/c23693ab-ef68-4762-b295-b74fdbf4eaa2.png

ERROR [geonetwork] - URL -> http://nameServer:8080/geonetwork/srv/api/records/09f38953-686e-474e-b65e-4f688c4f3ac6/attachments/IT88A-02.png

ERROR [geonetwork] - Error writing metadata to PDF
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://nameServer:8080/geonetwork/srv/api/records/09f38953-686e-474e-b65e-4f688c4f3ac6/attachments/IT88A-02.png
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1900)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1068)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.ImageReplacedElementFactory$UrlImageLoader.loadImage(ImageReplacedElementFactory.java:242)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.ImageReplacedElementFactory.loadImage(ImageReplacedElementFactory.java:182)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.ImageReplacedElementFactory.createReplacedElement(ImageReplacedElementFactory.java:150)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.calcDimensions(BlockBox.java:716)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.calcDimensions(BlockBox.java:666)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:809)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.InlineBoxing.layoutInlineBlockContent(InlineBoxing.java:405)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.InlineBoxing.layoutContent(InlineBoxing.java:302)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutInlineChildren(BlockBox.java:983)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.AnonymousBlockBox.layout(AnonymousBlockBox.java:47)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:321)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:299)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:967)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:847)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:321)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:299)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:967)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:847)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:321)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:299)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:967)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:847)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:321)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:299)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:967)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:847)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:321)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:299)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:967)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:847)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:321)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:299)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:967)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:847)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:321)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:299)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:967)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:847)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:776)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.layout(ITextRenderer.java:207)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi.writerAsPDF(FormatterApi.java:579)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi.writeOutResponse(FormatterApi.java:518)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi.getRecordFormattedBy(FormatterApi.java:339)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet.access$101(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:44)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet$1.doInTransaction(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:56)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet$1.doInTransaction(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:52)
    at jeeves.transaction.TransactionManager.runInTransaction(TransactionManager.java:73)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.fao.geonet.web.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.fao.geonet.monitor.webapp.WebappMetricsFilter.doFilter(WebappMetricsFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.fao.geonet.monitor.webapp.MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter.doFilter(MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.fao.geonet.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geonetwork.http.SessionTimeoutCookieFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutCookieFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.PassthroughFilter.doFilter(PassthroughFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

SOMEONE KNOWS HOW TO SOLVE THESE PROBLEM?

Answer (score 1):

```
ERROR [geonetwork.wro4j] - Error occurred during a wro4j request handling
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Cannot build valid CacheKey from request: /geonetwork/static/none
```

This error has been fixed in the 3.10.2 minor release available since 2020-04-05.

About the second one it seems you don't have permissions to view the attachment.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.
But what do you mean by "seems you don't have permissions to view the attachment"? The user who tries to download is an administrator, do you mean that there is a problem of permissions at the installation folder level?